# Fragmented MP4 file box editor

Tags: mp4

I'm looking for a GUI application for Windows or Linux which can modify MP4 boxes.

I don't want to edit the video, but I want to edit the fields in the boxes (I also do not want to insert or remove or reorder boxes).

Is there anything for this purpose or I will have to do it with a HEX-Editor?

Answer (score 1):

[ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) is the goto tool for editing metadata of Images & Video files. It is a command line utility but there is also a [GUI for Windows](https://exiftool.org/gui/) *(or several)* available there is also [pyExifToolGUI](https://hvdwolf.github.io/pyExifToolGUI/) which is cross platform.

Note that some metadata should not be tampered with, (as it can result in an unusable file), and ExifTool & the GUI honor the read-only flags. Attempting to edit with a hex editor is very likely to result in unusable files.

[image: ExifToolGUI]